# AEM querybuilder class return

Tags: java, jsp, pagination, aem, query-builder

I am attempting to use AEM's querybuilder API to do a generic search. The problem I am currently having is creating pagination with the querybuilder. While using the `ResultPage` class in AEM with SearchResult to `getNextPage()`. I am getting the result
`com.day.cq.search.impl.result.ResultPageImpl@541bd4bf`. How would I convert this into a URL? I already am using the offset and result total with the querybuilder but cannot find any more documentation to put me in the right direction.

```
  queryBuilder=resource.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(QueryBuilder.class);
//creating query based on the Query Description
Query query=queryBuilder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(map),session);
 //Getting and storing the Results
 List Pages1 = searchRes.getResultPages();
ResultPage nextpage = searchRes.getNextPage();
ResultPage lastpage = searchRes.getPreviousPage();
for (Hit hit:searchRes.getHits()){

String path1=hit.getPath();
String title1=hit.getTitle();
String excerpt1=hit.getExcerpt();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The `ResultPage` objects have information about your search results that you got from the `QueryBuilder`. You can use the information to build your own pagination and search result page(s).
As the `SearchResult` object contains only the results from the current page, you can use the `ResultPage` to easily get index and start of all the other pages that you could request from the `QueryBuilder`, based on the settings you used for your query, for example:

```
query.setStart(start);
query.setHitsPerPage(hitsPerPage);
```

But there is no connection to the frontend...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Oliver. How would I go about setting the pagination would it have to be with jquery? or does querybuilder support this in jsp?

Comment: Also could I use the Search.Result class which also has the getnextpage() method along with a method to get the URL.